# Regular Expression -- Cannot extract word after '

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `Bret 'Brook' Parker` and so far my code `r"(alt=\")([A-z]+ *\'*[A-z]+ *[A-z]+)"` extracts `'Bret 'Brook''`. Why is Parker left out, and how can I modify my code to include `'Parker'`?

This is the string I am extracting from: `<img height="44" width="32" alt="Bret \'Brook\' Parker" title="Bret \'Brook\' Parker" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/32x44/name-2138558783._CB468460248_.png" class="" />`

My desired output is `('alt="', "Bret 'Brook Parker")`

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not be using regex to parse HTML.  Instead, consider using the Beautiful Soup library:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(img.get('alt'))
```

Soup is primarily an HTML *parser*, and will crawl over your nested HTML text in a safe way.  Regex would only be appropriate here if you had a larger text with some HTML tags strewn throughout it.